If the norm of a continuous vector valued function is Fréchet differentiable at $a,$ is the vector valued function also Fréchet differentiable at $a?$
My question is motivated by this question, and this question, and attempts to generalize the first one to multiple dimensions.
Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuous vector-valued function, so that its $2$-Euclidean norm (the standard Euclidean norm) function $||F(x)||$ is Fréchet differentiable at $a\in \mathbb{R}^n.$ Does this necessarily imply that $F(x)$ is differentiable at $a?$ If not, is there a condition we can add to guarantee this differentiability?
Thanks in advance.

What do you mean by $2$-Euclidean norm? Isn't it just the Euclidean norm?

@mathcounterexamples.net Oh it's the standard Euclidean norm.

No, $F$ may not be Fréchet differentiable. For example, take $n = 1$, $m = 2$, and $F$ the map of a point that moves in a half circle centered at the origin and of radius equal to one, back and forth from one vertex of the half circle to the other with a constant speed.
For all $t \in \mathbb R$, we have $\lVert F(t) \rVert =1$. So $\lVert F \rVert$ is Fréchet differentiable. However, $F$ is not Fréchet differentiable for the values of $t$ for which the point stands at one of the extremities of the half circle.
From this example, I don't see a condition to add to $F$... apart from being Fréchet differentiable!
